# Remove indent when using enumerate

Tags: indentation

When we use the enumerate environment, there's an indent created as you can see in the picture:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that indent so that everytime I use the enumerate stuff doesn't give me such indent?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It is not entirely clear whether you want to eliminate the indentation entirely or whether you want the items to be indented but not the labels. A.Ellett interpreted your question in one way and I in another.

Here's my answer based on my interpretation. This takes it that you want to eliminate the indentation entirely so that the list is like a series of numbered paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{enumerate}[wide, labelwidth=!, labelindent=0pt]
    \item \kant[2]
    \item \kant[3]
    \item \kant[4]
    \item \kant[5]
  \end{enumerate}
  \kant[6]
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked enumeration]

- `wide` is a convenience style for non-indented lists which are paragraph-like.

More specifically (page 8 of the manual), this key is equivalent to setting

```
align=left, leftmargin=0pt, labelindent=\parindent, listparindent=\parindent, labelwidth=0pt, itemindent=!
```

That is, align the label left within the label box, set the `leftmargin` to zero, indent labels and paragraphs by `\parindent`, set the width of labels to zero and calculate an appropriate indentation for items based on the other values.

We then tweak this by overriding some of the settings used by `wide`:

- `labelindent=0pt` (overriding the value set by `wide`) says not to indent the label relative to the left margin.
- `labelwidth=!` tells `enumitem` to calculate the appropriate width for the label (again overriding the value set by `wide`).

Alternatively, the following is based on A.Ellett's interpretation which understood you to want indented items but non-indented labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
  \kant[1]
  \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
    \item \kant[2]
    \item \kant[3]
    \item \kant[4]
    \item \kant[5]
  \end{enumerate}
  \kant[6]
\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked enumeration]

- `leftmargin=*` calculates an appropriate value for `leftmargin` based on the current label.

Comment: Perhaps you might add the details about using `leftmargin=*`.

Comment: You make me laugh.  I appreciate the gesture.  But your answer was more thorough than mine.  All yours.  I think it's funny how we're simultaneously working on the same problems.

Comment: @A.Ellett You were first by 23 seconds. If anybody should delete, I should! But the answers were different and I thought it might be useful to have screenshots for both. I tried to leave you a comment suggesting you rollback if you objected but the system wouldn't let me because you'd deleted the answer.

Comment: How can I change numbering into bullet ? @cfr

Comment: Breaks when mdwlist suspend and resume is used inside the enumerate.

Answer (score 20):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm]
\item first item here
\item second item here
\item third item and so on ...
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]
\item first item here
\item second item here
\item third item and so on ...
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item first item here
\item second item here
\item third item and so on ...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, you can control the indentation value by specifying an option `[leftmargin=<length>]`. If you need it to be zero, just choose the `[leftmargin=*]` option. Sure you need to add `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the preamble.

You can get the customization you want by setting the `[key=value]` option for a number of keys. For example, for horizontal spacing, one can set the keys:

- **leftmargin**
- **rightmargin**
- **listparindent**
- **labelwidth**
- **labelsep**
- **itemindent**

For vertical spacing, one can set the keys:

- **topsep**
- **partopsep**
- **parsep**
- **itemsep**

You can refer to the `enumitem` [package documentation](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) for more details.

Comment: `leftmargin=*` this is the answer I've been looking for 20 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it without `enumitem` or other packages (`hyperref` is loaded only to test cross references and `lipsum` to fill the items with dummy text).

Works with or without indented items in the same environment.  As bonus point the items are capitalized:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{num}
\def\Num{\par\medskip\refstepcounter{num}{\bfseries\arabic{num}}.\hspace{1em}\MakeUppercase}
\def\num{\par\medskip\refstepcounter{num}\hangindent2em{\bfseries\arabic{num}}.\hspace{1em}\MakeUppercase}
\newenvironment{Numera}
{\parindent0pt\par\medskip}
{\setcounter{num}{0}\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\noindent Some text before. Go to item \ref{last}.
\begin{Numera}
\Num item one. \lipsum[2] \label{one}     
\Num another item. \lipsum[6]
\num indented item. \lipsum[7]     
\num one more item. \lipsum[11]\label{last} 
\end{Numera}
\noindent Some text after. Go to item \ref{one}.
\end{document}
```