# How to un-indent the item in an "enumerate" that's also inside a minipage

Tags: indentation, minipage, enumitem

I'm constructing a document aiming towards [Wildcard's checklist](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/513418/135381) and have come across an indentation that I can't convince LaTeX to omit.

One of the requirements for the checklist is that each (sub)section header, "objective" text, and *first* item of a list should all be colocated on one page; I'm using the minipage environment to accomplish this (since I don't want to unnecessarily force a `\pagebreak` if one's not needed). Other page-keeping approaches are welcome if minipage is a bad direction.

I've worked through the issues of restarting the item numbering, and I've tried the options at 
[Remove indent when using enumerate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241983/remove-indent-when-using-enumerate) to no avail. I've hacked at it while looking at Javier Bezos' [Customizing lists
with the enumitem package](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) but I obviously don't understand the pieces involved yet.

Sample input:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[top=0.75in]{geometry}
\title{\vspace{-2.0cm}\textbf{Title for the Whole Checklist}}
\date{}
\author{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\subsection*{INTRO SUBHEADER:}
\lipsum[1-5]

% the "SECTION 1", objective, and first step should all be on the same page
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\subsection*{\centering SECTION 1: NAME OF SECTION}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{2cm}
OBJECTIVE: \lipsum[2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[series=section1,label=\arabic*.]
  \item READ: \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{enumerate}[resume*=section1,label=\arabic*.]
  \item DO: something something
  \item READ: etc
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: indented first item]

Desired output would have the first item's label vertically aligned with the remaining items. The item text itself is wrapping and indented appropriately.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use a minipage here: if there is too much text you will get an overful box and will have to handle this manually anyway.

Comment: I'm open to better ideas, Ulrike, but am far from a TeX expert. Do you mean too much text inside the minipage? What is the end result of an "overful box"?

Comment: If the text of the first item is too long for the page, what do you think will happen? (Try e.g. \item READ: \lipsum[1-9]). So what do you gain by the minipage? If the text is short, it is unnecessary, if the text is too long it doesn't help (nothing would help, too much text is too much text).

Comment: I will check with @Wildcard to see what the best response is for an overfull page. If the text is short, I'm still concerned about a variable amount of text ahead of the elements causing a page break in the middle of the elements. A minipage has been my best idea so far. Maybe I should open a separate question, as this is slightly tangential to the indentation question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**: Add `\noindent` just before each minipage.

The minipage start a second paragraph, so it will be  indented (not the list, but the whole minipage) as any character, or any other box starting the horizontal mode.

Solution: Use `\noindent` if you want avoid indentation only in the paragraph with the minipage, or set `\parindent` to 0pt (i.e., `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`) somewhere before (the preamble is the best place to avoid indentation in all the document). To change indentation in some longer than one paragraph, change the setting again after each part, or use `{\setlength\parindent{0pt} ... }` to limit the scope of the command to the `...` part only.